# Algorithm for a (common? recursive?) scheduling optimizer

Tags: algorithm, recursion, schedule

I apologize in advance if this is a common problem with a well-known solution, or if this is in fact a very simple problem that I'm just not understanding.  Also, my apologies for such a vague title.  I'm not even sure what to call this particular problem.

I have a schedule that consists of three slots for each weekday.  So for Monday, we have Monday-Slot-1, Monday-Slot-2, Monday-Slot-3.  Likewise, we have Tuesday-Slot-1, Tuesday-Slot-2, etc.  As such, there are 15 slots total, three for each of the days Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday.

I also have a group of people that I need to populate this schedule with. Each person has a set of slots for which they are available. For example, "John" might be available for Monday-Slot-2, Wednesday-Slot-1, and Friday-Slot-3.  "Sally" might be available for Tuesday-Slot-3 and Friday-Slot-3.  Or "Frank" might be available for all slots but Friday-Slot-1.

I need to design an algorithm to assign people to slots such that I fill in as many slots as possible. The givens are:

> Each person will always have at least one slot for which they're available.
>
> There will be at least as many people as there are slots.

Ideally, I'd want to fill in all the slots, but I realize that the availability of the people may not make this possible.

Given its general nature, it would seem like this should be a common problem with a common algorithm.  Unfortunately, I'm not well-versed enough to know what specifically to search for or what this problem might even be known as.  If indeed this is a case of "Oh, that's just the so-and-so problem and it has a well-known algorithm," I'd love to know the name of the problem so I can research it further.  If not, I'd love to hear thoughts on what a workable algorithm might look like.

Thanks!

Comment: You might find some good information from the realm of operations research, one such algorithm that might be of use is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming

Comment: Here we might model all the people as one set of nodes in a bipartite graph, and the slots as an other set of nodes. If a person can be in a slot, there will be an edge. The maximum matching fills the most slots.